# Change Detection Chart from lists in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, chart, change-detection

I want to create a chart from classes area (square kilometers) that I calculated from the land cover supervised classification process. These classes area are in form of lists (these are printed in earth engine console). Since I created 3 year classification with 3 classes each year so I need to create change detection histogram chart (example attached).

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/cadca745cb6f033f684992c6c88e23e1

```
//SECTION 1 - TAHUN 2020
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(tangsel)
            .filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-04-30')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5)
            .first());

Map.centerObject(tangsel,11);
var vizParams2 = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.4,};
Map.addLayer(image.clip(tangsel), vizParams2, 'TRUE Landsat 2020');

var training_points = air_20.merge(urban_20).merge(vegetasi_20);
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var label = 'LC_20';
var sampling = image.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_points,
  properties: ['LC_20'],
  scale:30
});
print("Sampling:", sampling);

var trained = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(sampling, label, bands);
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(trained);
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(tangsel),
             {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'orange']},
             'classification 2020');

var area_2020 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000*1000).addBands(classified.clip(tangsel))
    .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'code',
    }),
    geometry: tangsel,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels:1e9
}).get('groups');

print('luas dalam km2 (2020):', area_2020);

//SECTION 2 - TAHUN 2010
var image_L5 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(tangsel)
            .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-11-30')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 50)
            .first());
            
var vizParams_L5 = {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.4,};
Map.addLayer(image_L5.clip(tangsel), vizParams_L5, 'TRUE Landsat 2010');

var training_points_10 = air_10.merge(urban_10).merge(vegetasi_10);
var bands_10 = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var label_10 = 'LC_10';
var sampling_10 = image_L5.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_points_10,
  properties: ['LC_10'],
  scale:30
});
print("Sampling:", sampling_10);

var trained_10 = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(sampling_10, label_10, bands_10);
var classified_10 = image_L5.select(bands_10).classify(trained_10);
Map.addLayer(classified_10.clip(tangsel),
             {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'orange']},
             'classification 2010');

var area_2010 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000*1000).addBands(classified_10.clip(tangsel))
    .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'code',
    }),
    geometry: tangsel,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels:1e9
}).get('groups');

print('luas dalam km2 (2010) :', area_2010);

//SECTION 3 - TAHUN 2000
var image_L5_00 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
            .filterBounds(tangsel)
            .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2000-12-30')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5)
            .first());

Map.addLayer(image_L5_00.clip(tangsel), vizParams_L5, 'TRUE Landsat 2000');
var training_points_00 = air_00.merge(urban_00).merge(vegetasi_00);
var bands_00 = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var label_00 = 'LC_00';
var sampling_00 = image_L5_00.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_points_00,
  properties: ['LC_00'],
  scale:30
});
print("Sampling:", sampling_00);

var trained_00 = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(sampling_00, label_00, bands_00);
var classified_00 = image_L5_00.select(bands_00).classify(trained_00);
Map.addLayer(classified_00.clip(tangsel),
             {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'orange']},
             'classification 2000');
             
var area_2000 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000*1000).addBands(classified_00.clip(tangsel))
    .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'code',
    }),
    geometry: tangsel,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels:1e9
}).get('groups');

print('luas dalam km2 (2000):', area_2000);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(tangsel, 0, 2), {}, 'Batas Tangsel');

//SECTION 4 - Tampilkan Grafik
var luas_coll = ee.FeatureCollection([area_2020, area_2010, area_2000]);
var luas_chart = ui.Chart.array.values(area_2020, 3).setChartType('ColumnChart');
print('Time Series luas :', luas_chart);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `ui.Chart.feature.groups` chart. That requires you to rearrange your data a bit. Here's one way to do that:

```
var labelByCode = ee.Dictionary({
  1: 'Air',
  2: 'Vegetation',
  3: 'Urban',
})

var features = ee
  .FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(null, {year: 2000, data: area_2000}),
    ee.Feature(null, {year: 2010, data: area_2010}),
    ee.Feature(null, {year: 2020, data: area_2020}),
  ])
  .map(function(feature) {
    var year = feature.getNumber('year')
    return ee.FeatureCollection(
      ee.List(feature.get('data'))
        .map(function(o) {
          o = ee.Dictionary(o)
          var code = o.getNumber('code')
          return ee.Feature(null, {
            year: year,
            code: code,
            label: labelByCode.get(code.format()),
            area: o.getNumber('sum')
          })
        })
    )
  })
  .flatten()
  
var chart = ui.Chart.feature
  .groups({
    features: features,
    xProperty: 'label',
    yProperty: 'area',
    seriesProperty: 'year'
  })
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
    
print(chart)
print(features)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/68df9a6d5286a7bc0e334d9bb2a3e05b

Comment: wow, amazing! thank you, really apreciat it! this is what i'm looking for.